# jQuery - On Mouse Over Change Text

Tags: jquery, html, hover

```
<span id="change">
    Stuff In Here
</span>

<script>
$("#change").on("mouseover", function () {
     $('#change').text("This is the new html");
});
</script>
```

The following doesn't work, as a jQuery noob, I'm not sure why.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a demo, because as-written that *should* work (assuming the `<script>...</script>` really *does* follow the element that it's meant to act upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<script>
 $("#change").on("mouseover", function () {
   $('#change').text("This is the new html");
 });
</script>
```

Because you are not referencing anything. Try this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#change").mouseover(function () {
      $('#change').text("This is the new html");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Well, there was another error in the fiddle. You had not selected any jQuery version in the upper left corner. After updating, the code worked perfectly, and from this I concluded that you might have not linked the script in your website.

Try linking the `script` file in the `head` section of your layout (website)

Here have a look now: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/HMhVn/3/

I have updated it, and it runs perfectly now :)

Comment: What's the error that you claim is present in your first code-block? And `$(document).ready(function(){/*...*/})` is an alias for `$(function(){/*...*/})` (as used in the other answer).

Comment: I had to update the answer, adding the fiddle which was the error. jquery version wasn't linked at all. So I mistakenly added the error in the top! my bad..

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! http://jsfiddle.net/HMhVn/6/

If you want, for more flexibility, you can cache the original string to access later by putting the text in a variable before you decide what do to on mouseover.

HTML:

```
<span id="change">
    Stuff In Here
</span>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready()
{
    $("#change").hover(
        function() // on mouseover
        {
            $(this).text("This is the new html");
        }, 

        function() // on mouseout
        {
            $(this).text("Stuff In Here");

        });
};
```

This allows you to change it permanently or not, it's up to do. Personally, I'd code it for flexibility.