# I want to change the text in a box when it is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a box that I want the text to change in when the h3 tag is hovered? What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Here is my html:

```
<h3>Hover me to find out more</h3>

<div id="next-text">Here is where you find out more.</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
 h3 {
        border: 3px solid hsl(288, 49%, 29%);
        border-radius: 20px;
        line-height: 40px;
        padding: 52px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 19%;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 15px;
        height: 305px;
    }
```

Also I have multiple h3 tags and divs.

Comment: how do you want it to change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - On Mouse Over Change Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471692/jquery-on-mouse-over-change-text)

Comment: Do you want to change the text, or add to it like this? http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/z1heg5yg/

Comment: I would like to change the text.

Comment: Hi Emma, I’ve had a look at some of your questions after noticing that you have asked a few but have quite a poor reputation. This site is quite fussy on quality questions and answers and does ban users who consistently ask poor quality questions. I’d strongly encourage you to spend some time reading the topics in http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. You will get a lot of value out of this site if used correctly. 
The other part, make sure you research properly before asking (like this question). Had you googled what you typed as the heading here, you would have found quite a few answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change text color inside box on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021916/change-text-color-inside-box-on-hover)

Answer (score 1):

hover event has two function mouseenter and mouseleave

```
$( "h3" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).text( "changed text" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).text( "Hover me to find out more" );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
var oldtext = null;
$("h3").hover(
    function() {
      oldtext = $(this).text();
      $(this).text("changed text");
    }, function() {
       $(this).text(oldtext);
    }
);
```

Refer this [jquery hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/184/

**JS**

```
$('h3').hover(
    function() {
        var $this = $(this); 
        $this.data('originalText', $this.text());
        $this.text("Hover text");
    },
    function() {
        var $this = $(this); 
        $this.text($this.data('originalText'));
    }
);
```

**HTML**

```
<h3>Hover me to find out more</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try follwing using jquery:

```
$('h3').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).next('div').html('changed text');
})
```

If you want to get original text back on mouse leave then do like following.

```
var previous='';    
$('h3').mouseenter(function() {
        previous=$(this).next('div').html();
        $(this).next('div').html('changed text');
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).next('div').html(previous);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$( "h3" ).hover(function() {
    $( this ).text("new text");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text content to change use one of the other answers (preferebly @WisdmLabs):

```
$( "h3" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).text( "changed text" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).text( "Hover me to find out more" );
  }
);
```

if you want the **styling** to change add a `h3:hover` to your css.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to using css then try this:

```
html:
<h3><span>Hello!</span></h3>

css:
h3:hover span {display:none}
h3:hover:before {content:"Reply!"}
```

or using JS then try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/184/

Answer (score 0):

```
div.project h1, div.project h3, div.project p {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.8s;   
}
div.project:hover h1, div.project:hover h3, div.project:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: my findings for @emma